# How to use chrome inspect element to find Restful API

Tags: google-chrome

say, I click a button on my page. It calls a specific Restful API. How can I find the one which is called?

I tried right clicking on the button and clicked Inspect element. Then goto the Network tab, there's are a lot of Rest API and its very difficult to find the one I'm looking for.

Regards.

Comment: First clear all the APIs and click the button

Comment: If it's an XHR, choosing XHR tab instead of All might be useful